# Is there any standard notation for two states being "equivalent up to a global phase"?

Tags: terminology-and-notation

Is there any standard notation for two states "equivalent up to a global phase"?

Currently, I use just an equal sign but I'd like to use a different symbol to distinguish between two phases that are exactly the same (equal sign) and two phases which are "equivalent up to a global phase" (some other symbol).

Comment: You could use the standard notation for an equivalence relation i.e. $|\psi\rangle \sim |\phi\rangle$ after defining the relation $\sim$.

Comment: $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$